# Variable Not Accessible from within function objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have created an outlet for a textview and I'm trying to use it in a function, outside of the function it works fine, inside its not declared. When I pass it along with the function like StartFunction(textBox) it works fine, but this function also has to work with a bunch of other things like this and I don't like the idea of just passing everything with the function.

What would be a better alternative?

```
// Header File
- (IBAction)startButton_clicked:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textBox;

// Main file
- (IBAction)startButton_clicked:(id)sender {
    if (currentlyOn == false) StartFunction(headLabel);
        else textBox.text = @"Already Started"; // Works fine here
            }

void StartFunction(UILabel *_headLabel)
{
    _headLabel.text = @"This works fine because it's passed with the function";
    textBox.text = @"textBox is undeclared here";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use a *method* rather than a *function* for your situation.

A *method* is really a type of *function* which is silently passed a *reference* to an instance of itself, this is given the name `self`. Using that reference the method can access *instance variables*, *methods* and *properties*. Uses of `self` are also often silently added for you.

So, assuming your code is part of `myClass` your method `startButton_clicked` is **approximately** (we're glossing over a few details) the same as the function:

```
IBAction startButton_clicked(myClass *self, id sender)
{
    if (currentlyRecording == false)
       StartRecordingAudio(headLabel);
    else
       self.textBox.text = @"Already Started"; // Works fine here
}
```

Note the extra argument and the use of `self` in the assignment. The method call:

```
[someInstanceOfMyClass startButton_clicked:theSender];
```

is **approximately** equivalent to:

```
startButton_clicked(someInstanceOfMyClass, theSender);
```

which is where the silently passed `self` comes from.

*Functions* are not treated in this way at all, there is no hidden argument passed, and lacking that silent way to access instance variables, properties and methods.

Both methods and functions have their uses and you select based on the need. In your case it sounds like you need a method as you wish to access an instance.

HTH.

Comment: it's rather `startButton_clicked(instance, @selector(buttonClicked), sender);` :)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Hence the **approximately** - included the essential details only to explain what is going on.

Comment: I see.. Confusing language :P Oh well I'll get the hang of it at some point ^^ Thanks

Comment: @user1071461 - Some languages have only functions, some only methods, and some both. The latter include languages which started as, or evolved from, function-based. C++ is a well-known example, and Objective-C is clarity itself when compared to that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Functions are not a part of the class, they don't have access to instance variables. Why not just make this function an instance method?

Answer (score 0):

A plain C function can't be used as a member of an Objective-C class.

Declaring it in your implementation does not change that.

Use an Objective-C method, or pass the object(s) to your C function (if they have public iVars, which is usually bad design, or if you can use properties).

First solution is always better. You can use a class extension if you don't want the method's prototype to appear in your public header file.